# Solve High-order PDE (Partial Differential Equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, linear-pde

I'm trying to solve this equation:$$A\frac{∂^4h}{∂x^4}+B\frac{∂^5h}{∂t∂x^4}+C\frac{∂^2h}{∂t^2}=\frac{∂\delta(x-a)}{∂x}D\sin(\Omega t),$$where $A,B,C,a,D, \Omega $ are constant, $\delta(x)$ is dirc function.

Boundary conditions are:

$[-D+A\frac{∂^2h}{∂x^2}+B\frac{∂^3h}{∂t∂x^2}]_{x=0}=0$, $[-D+A\frac{∂^2h}{∂x^2}+B\frac{∂^3h}{∂t∂x^2}]_{x=l}=0$

$[-D+A\frac{∂^2h}{∂x^3}+B\frac{∂^3h}{∂t∂x^3}]_{x=0}=0$, $[-D+A\frac{∂^2h}{∂x^3}+B\frac{∂^3h}{∂t∂x^3}]_{x=l}=0$

What kind of techniques or methods should I use? Thank you!

Comment: What is the domain of $t$? On the right side you have the partial derivative of $\delta'$, is that a mistake?

Comment: @maxmilgram $t$ is the time, so the domain of $t$ is that $t>0$. Yes, it's a mistake. Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: So i guess you have some kind of initial conditions as well?

Comment: @maxmilgram Good question. That's one of the key points of this problem. There is no initial conditions for $t$. We have to make an assumption or substitution.